# Exercise: Build a news page with React & React Router

Tags: javascript, jquery, react.js

From a React course I'm taking:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I could implement most of the demands.

A life-demo can be seen here:

http://n-or.de/news/#/

You have to click the "News" and "Photos" links on the right side for getting to the subpages.

Here's the code of the relevant components:

**main.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var CreateHashHistory = require('history/lib/createHashHistory');

var History = new CreateHashHistory({
    queryKey: false
});

var Frame = require('./components/Frame.jsx');
var ArticleList = require('./components/ArticleList.jsx');
var Photos = require('./components/Photos.jsx');

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={ History }>
    <Route path="/" component={ Frame }>
      <Route path="/articles" component={ ArticleList }></Route>
      <Route path="/photos" component={ Photos }></Route>
    </Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**Frame.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

var Frame = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="header">
                <div className="row upper-header">
                    <h1 className="large-9 columns">
                      <Link to="/">Country News</Link>
                    </h1>
                    <div className="logos large-3 columns">
                      <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                        <img src="./imgs/twitter.png" alt="twitter_logo" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://de-de.facebook.com/">
                        <img src="./imgs/facebook.jpg" alt="facebook_logo" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
                        <img src="./imgs/instagram.jpg" alt="instagram_logo" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://de.linkedin.com/">
                        <img src="./imgs/linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin_logo" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="mailto:willie.meyer@whatever.com">
                        <img src="./imgs/mail_32.png" alt="mail_logo" />
                      </a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    <p className="sub-title large-12 columns">Top stories in my country</p>
                </div>  

                <div className="row links-subpages">
                    <div className="large-offset-10 large-1 columns">
                        <Link to="/articles">News</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="large-1 columns">
                        <Link to="/photos">Photos</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>        
              </div>

              <div className="content">
                  { this.props.children }
              </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Frame;
```

**Photos.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var photoList = [ { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: 'fe00fe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: '0034fe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: 'aa00fe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: '0077fe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: 'fe77fe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: '39abfe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: '2377fe' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: '5977ab' },
                  { urlThumb: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/',
                    urlPhoto: 'http://placehold.it/700x300/',
                    color: '0022ab' } ];

var Photos = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    var figureList = photoList.map(function(photo, i) {
      return (
        <div className="large-4 medium-2 columns end">
          <figure>
            <a href={ photo.urlPhoto + photo.color } className="popup">
              <img src={ photo.urlThumb + photo.color } alt="illustration_photo" 
                   className="thumbnail" title="Click to enlarge" />
            </a>
          </figure>
        </div>);
    });

    return (
      <div className="row photos">
        { figureList }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Photos;
```

**Article.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var Article = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var key = 'id_' + this.props.id;
        return (
          <div className="row article">
            <div className="left-col large-2 columns">
              <figure>
                <img src={ this.props.avatar } className="avatar-image" 
                     alt="avatar_picture" />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="right-col large-10 columns">
              <h1>{ this.props.title }</h1>
              <h2>{ this.props.subtitle }</h2>
              <p>{ this.props.text }</p>
              <div>
                <img src={ this.props.firstImage } 
                     className="thumbnail" alt="thumbnail_image" />
                <img src={ this.props.secondImage }
                     className="thumbnail" alt="thumbnail_image" />
              </div>
              <p>{ this.props.location }</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Article;
```

**ArticleList.jsx**

```
$bodyColor: #cdcdcd;
$headerColor: blue;
$fontStack: Futura, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
$borderRadius: 4px;

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: $bodyColor; 
    font-family: $fontStack;
    overflow: scroll;
}

ul.article-list {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.header {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $headerColor;
}

.thumbnail {
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px grey;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.article, .photos {
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.links-subpages {
    padding: 10px;
}

.links-subpages a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.links-subpages a:hover {
    background: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.sub-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.upper-header { 
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.upper-header a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.links-subpages a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: $headerColor;
}

.logos {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.logos a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}

.logos a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.avatar-image {
  border-radius: $borderRadius;
  border: 1px solid $bodyColor;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

The complete code (jQuery, Sass etc) can be seen on GitHub:

https://github.com/mizech/country-news

Is my implementation done in a proper way?

Where could I improve and where a weak points?

Moreover:

After publishing a prior exercise on CodeReview ( [Building a multi-panel display with React and Bootstrap](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138060/building-a-multi-panel-display-with-react-and-bootstrap) ) I was criticized (rightly) for writing all variables inside the render function. So that these variables are recreated every time the function is called.

I have tried to avoid variables within render() this time. **But I don't know how to pass the data as props to ArticleList.jsx and Photos.jsx .**

Within Frame.jsx the components are called via { this.props.children } .
How can I pass the image-URLs and article-data via props from main.jsx or Frame.jsx?